# How to follow type inferences in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Couldn't really follow the type inferences below, where case 1 worked but case 2 failed, why?

```
ghci> :t sqrt . maximum . map (+1)   -- case 1

(Floating c, Ord c) => [c] -> c

ghci> :t sqrt . maximum . map length -- case 2

Could not deduce (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
from the context (Foldable t)
bound by the inferred type of it :: Foldable t => [t a] -> Int
```

**@EDIT**

On OOP , `Num` is ususally the lower bound for all its `subtypes` e.g. `Int` and `Float`. Hence, `Int` will be inferentially acceptable if `Num` is the qualified type, but not vice versa.

Besides, on C-like languages, the built-in number conversion can automatically fulfill the case from the lower precision to the higher e.g. from `Int` to `Float`.

In contrast, on Haskell with [HM type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system), `Num` is the `class` for all its `instances` e.g. `Int` and the `subclasses` e.g. `Floating`. The qualified types can be bi-inferred between the ancestor and the descendant e.g. from `Num` to `Int`, `Floating` or vice versa, but not between `Int` and `Floating`.

To remedy case 2, `Int` should firstly be adapted to `Num` by `fromIntegral` or exerting `Data.List.genericLength` to produce the `Num` - the inferentially qualified type for `Floating` that `sqrt`requires.

Let's apply the aforementioned points to follow the type inferences below,

```
ghci> :t (+)
Num a => a -> a -> a

ghci> :t 1.1
Fractional a => a

ghci> :i Fractional
class Num a => Fractional a
instance Fractional Float
instance Fractional Double

ghci> :t 1
Num a => a

ghci> :t length [1]
Int 

ghci> :i Int
instance Num Int    
instance Real Int 
instance Integral Int 

ghci> :t 1.1 + 1          -- case 1
Fractional a => a

ghci> :t 1.1 + length [1] -- case 2
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal ‘1.1’
```

Comment: The `length` function returns an `Int`, but `sqrt` expects a type with a `Floating` instance. Try using `genericLength` from `Data.List` instead, which can produce any type with a `Num` instance.

Comment: Your summary is incorrect. Type classes are not types. You cannot convert from Num to Int, or Int to Floating. These are apples and oranges.  Type classes constrain a type. You may have, for example, `Floating a => a -> a -> a` which says that `a` must have a Floating instance. `Float` does, `Int` does not.

Comment: @erisco, The point is `type inference`, my wording may mislead you to think of the conversion  between `type class` and `type` etc.

Comment: The literal `1` can be inferred as any Num type. In the first case, `sqrt` has the constraint Floating, and `1` the constraint Num, which simplifies to just the constraint Floating (because Floating implies Num). In the second case, `length` has the constraint `(~) Int`, but this is unsatisfied because `Int` has no Floating instance.

Comment: Also I should add, `fromIntegral` weakens the Integral constraint to the Num constraint. `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`. Arguably this should not exist because of adverse consequences such as `fromIntegral 1000 :: Word8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` can be any type of number and `+` can work with any type of number. The same is true for `maximum`. Thus `maximum . map (+1)` is a function that can can take a list of any type of number and produce a number of the same type as its result. This includes both integral numbers and floating point numbers.

However `length` will specifically produce an `Int`. It can not produce any other type of number. So `maximum . map length` can take any list and produce a result of type `Int`, not of any other numeric type.

Now `sqrt` needs its argument to be a floating point number. So in the first case type inference figures out that you must provide a list of floating point numbers, so the result of `maximum . map (+1)` will be a floating point number that can be passed to `sqrt`.

However the second case simply can not work because `Int` is not a floating point type and `maximum . map length` can't produce anything other than an `Int`. So this causes an error.

You can use the `fromIntegral` function to convert the result of `length` to any numeric type to make the second code work.

Comment: could you kindly have a look at my edited post for reviewing whether it's properly summarized? Thanks!